# How to split string based on position in string

Tags: python

Given the following text:

```
input_value= """12
23
54"""
```

I want to return lists with the first and second elements of each line:

```
[[1,2,5], [2,3,4]]
```

I am trying to achieve this using a one-liner but struggling to access the correct indexes of each line and then placing them into a separate list. The number of returned lists should be equal to the number of digits present on each line:

I've tried the following as a base but clearly requires more logic in order to retrieve the correct digits:

```
new_list = [[elem] for elem in input_value.split('\n')]
```

Comment: this works well but the returns list have the digits in string type how can they be int?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a nested [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
out = [[int(i) for i in x] for x in zip(*input_value.split('\n'))]
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 5], [2, 3, 4]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like

```
[[*elems] for elems in zip(*input_value.split("\n"))]
```

EDIT:
To create a list of integers, use

```
[[*map(int, elems)] for elems in zip(*input_value.split("\n"))]
```

Comment: this works well but the returns list have the digits in string type how can they be int?

Comment: @danielstafford Replace `[*elems]` with `[*map(int,elems)]` or with `[int(c) for c in elems]`

Answer (score 1):

```py
input_value= """12
23
54
"""

lst1 = []
lst2 = []
for i in input_value.splitlines():
    if i:
        lst1.append(int(i[0]))
        lst2.append(int(i[1]))

lst = [lst1, lst2]
print(lst)
```

See if this works.

Comment: what if lines have more than 2 digits?

Comment: This works if you have small numbers.

Comment: Yes, this works but doesn't cover for more digits

Comment: not really, it works ONLY if you have double digits

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```
[[list(map(int,x))[y] for x in input_value.split()] for y in range(2)]
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 5], [2, 3, 4]]
```